# Insert Ad in the Body Field D8

Tags: theming, javascript, hooks

Looking for a simple solution that will allow you to insert a script such as Google Adsense ad or HTML in the Body field of a content type.

The insert can be after the first five paragraph tags in the Body field. Or maybe in the middle of content.

While on Wordpress there were a lot of plugins to do this, in Drupal I can't find a solution. There are blocks, but you can't inject them in the middle of content.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Tried this in as a module but can't get it to work.

```
<?php

function adinject_node_view(array &$build, 
\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, 
\Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {

if ($entity->getType() == 'vehicle_repair_guides' && $view_mode == 'full') {
$pieces = explode('<p>', $build['body'][0]['#text']);
$new_text = '';
foreach ($pieces as $key => $value) {
$new_text .= '<p>' . $value;
if ($key == 2) {
$new_text .= '<p>AD GOES HERE!</p>';
}
}
$build['body'][0]['#text'] = $new_text;
}
}
```

Comment: I'd advise against this (the code above). Instead, I would look for using some sort of token to do this. Perhaps https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter

Comment: Hi Kevin. Thanks for the reply. What is the concern with the above code? Just looked at token module, but to me it seems that you manually have to insert the token in the body. The goal is to automatically inject the code in the body of all nodes of certain content type.

Comment: As far as the Drupal part of this goes, you just need to alter the last line so it provides your changes in a proper render array. At its simplest, that'd be something like `$build['body'] = ['#markup' => $new_text];`. The rest of isn't something you're likely to get help with here, injecting arbitrary HTML into the middle of other arbitrary HTML isn't something Drupal can help you with, it's a general PHP task. Tokens are the way to do it without custom code. I just checked, I couldn't find any Wordpress plugins that have this functionality. They're all based on shortcodes or manual PHP

Comment: I see your point. Would it be possible to inject a block into the BODY field?  The same requirement. After the 3rd or 5th paragraph. This would have to be done via code and not manually. Can apply to certain content type.

Comment: You're still looking at tokens.

Comment: Yeah to expand on what Kevin said, your problem is more that you need to inject something into the middle of an HTML string, not what you put there as such. If you can wedge it in there it can be a token, sure, or a rendered block, a token which eventually resolves to a rendered block, a rendered theme item, a manually constructed HTML string, anything that the browser will understand at the other end. I can only recommend not to use split functions to edit HTML, it's bound to end badly. Use `DOMDocument` to comprehend and manipulate it 'properly' so you don't have to worry about edge cases

Comment: Thanks Clive and Kevin. You guys are pointing me in the right direction. Can you expand a little on the DOMDocument solution to help a non-programer? :)

Comment: There's an almost perfect example right here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39984379/how-to-insert-new-element-after-specific-element-in-html-using-php. You might need to combine it with something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978822/export-particular-element-in-domdocument-to-string. Good luck!

Comment: Clive, I am not having that much luck implementing this. How much time do you think is needed to write this as a module? Would this even be a module?  Thanks.